# How to run Python task with build variables in Azure Devops

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, yaml

I am using the following script tested locally but I cant figure out how to grab the build variable and insert into the request in the Python code in the Azure Devops yml.

I have the following build variables defined:
DATABRICKS_HOST, DATABRICKS_TOKEN, CLUSTER

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Start Databricks Cluster'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import os
      import requests
      DOMAIN = os.environ.get('DATABRICKS_HOST')
      TOKEN = os.environ.get('DATABRICKS_TOKEN')
      CLUSTER_ID = os.environ.get('CLUSTER')
      response = requests.post('https://%s/api/2.0/clusters/start' % (DOMAIN),headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN},json={ "cluster_id": CLUSTER_ID  }  )
      if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Error launching cluster")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [use pipeline variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline), try the following yaml.

```
variables:
  DATABRICKS_HOST: "test"

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      host = "$(DATABRICKS_HOST)"
      print (host)
```

If you [set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts), please check the following yaml.

```
steps:
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATABRICKS_TOKEN]crushed tomatoes"
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      token = "$(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)"
      print (token)
```

Please note [Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu latest agents](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#language-and-runtime) use python3 syntax.

Comment: Hi ibexy, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.